# Syntax for using data-masking functions in dplyr::distinct()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to merge rows that have duplicated entries in the ID column, by retrieving the means of each column.

In `dplyr::distinct()`'s documentation it states that distinct can take a data-masking function as input and return new values for the resulting column.

I used an example from the help pages. However, I am unable to get it to work properly, and could use some help with the syntax.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(
    "ID" = rep(1:3, each = 2) %>% as.numeric(),
    "x" = rep(1:3, each = 2) %>% as.numeric(),
    "y" = 1:6 %>% as.numeric()
)

# Original dataframe
a

A data.frame: 6 × 3
ID  x   y
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   1   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
2   2   4
3   3   5
3   3   6
```

The example from the Help pages:

```
grouped_mean <- function(df, var, ...) {
  df %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

distinct(a, ID, grouped_mean(a,ID), .keep_all = TRUE)

# Output
A data.frame: 3 × 4
ID  x   y   mean
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   1   1   2
2   2   3   2
3   3   5   2
```

Instead of evaluating column means for each ID, it creates a new column with called mean.

I tried adding a piece of code I have used earlier for calculating grouped column means in a function:

```
row_mean <- function(df, var, ...) {
summarise(
    across(
        .cols = everything(), 
        .fns = ~ mean(as.numeric(.x), 
            na.rm = TRUE)
    )
)}

distinct(a, ID, row_mean(a,ID), .keep_all = TRUE)

A data.frame: 3 × 3
ID  x   y
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   1   1
2   2   3
3   3   5
```

However, it only returns the first row of each ID value, as the default function does.

What I want:

```
A data.frame: 3 × 3
ID  x   y
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   1   1.5   # <-- column means for each unique ID
2   2   3.5   # <--
3   3   5.5   # <--
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want `distinct` in this case. Just use grouped summary, which returns the distinct groups anyway.

```r
a %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    across(
      .fns = mean
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>      ID     x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1   1.5
#> 2     2     2   3.5
#> 3     3     3   5.5
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I realised too. I was more curious if some convenience functions could be used within `distinct()`. If  I understand your example correctly, I dont actually need to add `.cols = everything()` in `across()`?

Comment: The example you use @PålBjartan is not a data masking function, it's an example of the indirection in the `...` argument, because you don't need to embrace it. The `distinct()` function expects column names to count distinct from, not a convenience function. However, if you want to use tidy selectors, you can use `distinct(df, across(...))` where you could use a convenience function to **select columns**.

Comment: Ok, I was a bit confused what they meant by data masking. In the scenario that you want to remove for duplicates in a column, but set `.keep_all = TRUE`, it makes little sense that the function can only preserve the first row. Your example is sort of what I've been looking for though. I tried getting row means by `a %>% distinct(across(everything(), mean))`, however this only returns the means when `ID == 2`.